# href link to a component in index.html

Tags: html, angular

I have an `html` template with a menu. I put this template in the `index.html` under `/src` folder, and I want to link each menu element in the menu to an `angular component`. Here is the menu:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">

<!-- Menu Items Start -->
        <li class="active treeview">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-project-diagram"></i> <span> Projects</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="active treeview">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-tv"></i> <span>Applications</span>
            </a>
        </li>

<!-- /Menu Items End -->

</ul>

 <div class="content-wrapper">

      <app-root></app-root>

 </div>
```

How can I link each element in the menu to its component ?

I've tried:

```
<a routerLink="app/projects/projects.components.html">
```

but it does't work.

Comment: Consider reading the documentation, which is there for that : https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement routing for your project. Please refer below angular routing tutorial for details explaination [link](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-the-approutingmodule)

Create a New Module Called Routing
app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ProjectComponent } from './projects/projects.components';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'project', component: ProjectComponent }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Import the file in app.module.ts

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

and your router link will be like below

```
<a routerLink="project">
```

In app.component.html add Below Code.

```
<app-header></app-header> //This is new header component selector
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Create New component header and in html add your navigation code below in html.

```
<li class="active treeview">
            <a routerLink="project">
                <i class="fa fa-project-diagram"></i> <span> Projects</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="active treeview">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-tv"></i> <span>Applications</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: thank you. that is helpful. Please Now my link in index.html is not clickable.

Comment: I think that only works if I use the link inside another componenet but in my case i want it to be inside index.html

Comment: Why Index.html. In angular your all components should reside in app folder only.
Just create one Header component and add your href links.. Wait I will update that in my answer